# Checking time using a discord bot (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I want to check the time difference between when a command is executed and when the parameter specified in the command states it should end. I have an idea of how to do this, but if i merely stick a loop in my index.js which is the main file that I have the command group names stored will the loop continue to run without it stopping the bot from receiving input from people typing a command in a discord channel (like !flip)? How would I go about making it so it won't stop the other input if it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need to make use of async as otherwise node will wait for the loop to finish.
Try putting

```
<client>.on('message', async message => { /*code*/})
```